# how can i convert "&#1585;&#1575;&#1605;" to normal text

Tags: php

in arabic page
after using this function

```
function getNodeOuterHTML($n) {
    $d = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $b = $d->importNode($n->cloneNode(true),true);
    $d->appendChild($b);
    $h = $d->saveHTML();
    return utf8_decode($h);
}
```

it gives `"&#1585;&#1575;&#1605; &#1575;&#1604;&#1604;&#1607;"` its arabic work calls "رام الله"

How can i convert it to that arabic text, it appear in the browser arabic but not in the source

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php - not tested for your case, but you'll probably have to pass utf-8 to the encoding variable

Comment: What do you mean by "but not in the source" ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `html_entity_decode`; it will decode also numeric entity references like these.

```
echo html_entity_decode("&#1585;&#1575;&#1605; &#1575;&#1604;&#1604;&#1607;");
```

Output: رام الله

If you are using an old version of PHP you have to pass the encoding parameter. Before 5.4 the ISO-8859-1 encoding was assumed.

```
echo html_entity_decode($str, ENT_COMPAT|ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: put not in the source

Comment: It does not matter where the input is.